# How to add a new element for array using ruamel library in python?

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a yaml file which I want to change using ruamel. I am able to change it if the deployment contains only one environment. The problem is I want to add/change more than one environment.
Here is a sample code which works for one environment using 2 arguments.

sample.py

```
import ruamel.yaml
import sys

file_name = 'Jenkinsfile.yaml'
from ruamel.yaml.util import load_yaml_guess_indent

config, ind, bsi = load_yaml_guess_indent(open(file_name))

totalArgs = len(sys.argv) - 1
print(totalArgs)
print(sys.argv[1:])

if totalArgs == 2:
    deploy = config['deploy']
    deploy[0]['env'] = sys.argv[1]
    deploy[0]['org'] = sys.argv[2]

elif totalArgs == 4:
    deploy = config['deploy']

    deploy[0]['env'] = sys.argv[1]
    deploy[0]['org'] = sys.argv[2]

    deploy[0]['env'] = sys.argv[3]
    deploy[0]['org'] = sys.argv[4]
    deploy[0]['host'] = 'https://**.com'
    deploy[0]['loc'] = 'saas'
    deploy[0]['manifest'] = 'manifest_dev.yml'
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(config, open('Jenkinsfile.yaml', 'w'), 
                            indent=ind, block_seq_indent=bsi)
```

Result

sample.py mitul-trial test

```
deploy:
- env: mitul-trial (Will change)
  org: test (Will change)
  host: https://**.com (will remain same)
  loc: saas (will remain same)
  manifest: manifest_dev.yml (will remain same)
  approval: true (will remain same)
```

Wanted result:

sample.py mitul-trial test mitul1 testsomething

```
deploy:
- env: mitul-trial (Will change)
  org: test (Will change)
  host: https://**.com (will remain same)
  loc: saas (will remain same)
  manifest: manifest_dev.yml (will remain same)
  approval: true (will remain same)

- env: mitul1 (Will change)
  org: testsomething (Will change)
  host: https://**.com (will remain same)
  loc: saas (will remain same)
  manifest: manifest_dev.yml (will remain same)
  approval: true (will remain same)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working, because you are not adding a new element to the sequence/list that is the value for key `deploy`. You are just assigning the first entry new values.

There are several ways to copy such a value, but since it is a dict, you need to make sure you are not copying a reference (which would result in updating the first element as well). In such cases you are better of using `copy.deepcopy()` from the standard library, to be on the safe side. For that include

```
from copy import deepcopy
```

You `elif` code should therefore read:

```
elif totalArgs == 4:
    elem = deepcopy(config['deploy'][0])
    config['deploy'].append(elem)

    elem['env'] = sys.argv[1]
    elem['org'] = sys.argv[2]

    elem['env'] = sys.argv[3]
    elem['org'] = sys.argv[4]
    elem['host'] = 'https://**.com'
    elem['loc'] = 'saas'
    elem['manifest'] = 'manifest_dev.yml'
```

to get the output you want.

Comment: Thanks Anthon for the quick reply. This works for my original question. I have bashed by for a while before posting.